# How to specify which processor to do a task in Python

Tags: python

Is this something doable?

I have 12 core PC

and I have 12 tasks

I want to specify task 1 to be done on CPU 0

task 2 to CPU 1

etc.

I know about multi-thread

but this is not my question

my question is about specifying a task to a specific processor.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? (Why not just rely on the OS to do the assignment?)

Comment: Processes can be assigned to one or more specified cores (search keyword: "process affinity") but it is system-dependent and needs either ctypes or an external library.

Comment: @MichaelButscher anywhere you recommend i can check for more info?

Comment: @les this is for school work

Comment: This is slightly old, but it may help you.  https://sorami-chi.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/04/29/000000